# Split windows path

Tags: java, regex

Can anybody show me how to split windows path on folders, file and drive ?
Do I need regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegExp? Yes and No - you can use `String#split` which uses a regular expression even though it often *feels* like using a normal String:

```
  String[] parts = "C:\\Program Files\\Application\\config.txt".split("\\\\");
```

This results in drive (`parts[0]`), folders (`parts[1]` and `parts[2]`) and filename (`parts[parts.length-1]`)

You may have to test *if* the first segment is a drive name (ends with ":"), the last segment is a file name (`file.isDirectory()`) and if a segment contains a folder (like no folder in `C:\test.txt`.

Comment: ... now the java code is correct, 4 backslashes are needed for split ;)

Comment: That sort of fixing is the reason not to use regexes here especially as File does all that is needed.

Comment: I got in app path="C:\test\test" and I wrote String[] temp=path.split("\\"); but it just stop at split and not exception, nothing, just stop

Comment: @Mark - one requirement was to get the "drive letter" segment. `File` does not support it, you'll have to extract it from the parent path (which might bring us back to this solution...)

Comment: @Damir - have a close look at the *number* of backslashes in my example. It is tested and works.

Comment: filelocation = C:\Apps\xxx\abc\Brazil\name\100kowledgment.pdf      how i will split this   String path[] = filelocation.split("\\");    error

Answer (score 8):

No regex needed use [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) part of the standard library.

Especially the `getName()`, `getParent()` and `getParentFile()` methods which will be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need split at nix platform windows file name or vice versa:

```
Pattern pt=Pattern.compile("\\\\\\\\|\\\\/");
String[] ar=pt.split("c:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc");
String[] ar1=pt.split("/tmp/aaa/ddd");
System.out.println(ar[ar.length-1]);
System.out.println(ar1[ar1.length-1]);
```